# Using the Requests for PHP library, how can I set a custom user-agent?

Tags: php

I'm doing some testing of [Requests for PHP](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) and I'd like to set a custom user-agent for a basic GET request.

Peeking at the source code, I thought perhaps this test would pass:

```
$url = 'http://httpbin.org/user-agent';
$user_agent = 'my-test-agent';

$options = array('useragent', $user_agent);
$response = Requests::get($url, array(), $options);
$json = json_decode($response->body, true);

$this->assertEqual($json['user-agent'], $user_agent);
```

However, http://httpbin.org/user-agent returns the default library value `php-requests/1.6` as the user-agent.

Is it possible to do this or do I need to use the `Requests_Session` object as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/blob/master/examples/session.php)?

Comment: When you just use `Requests::get`, the second parameter passes HTTP headers “as-is”, so you will have to use the right header name instead of `useragent` (which Requests_Session seems to handle internally).

Comment: It looks to me like `useragent` is an option, not a header. In any event, passing a `useragent` header as the second parameter did not change the result.

Comment: Yes, it’s an option to set when using `Requests_Session`. If you want a special header to be set when using `Requests::get`, then just do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the options this way:

```
$options = array('useragent' => $user_agent);
```